# Bash cat/grep prevent real-time update

Tags: bash, grep

I am running many separate experiments on a server. These experiments automatically redirect their stdout to an `.out` file specified by me. I need to determine if an experiment failed so I can restart it. A failure is due to a failed module installation, so I use the following command:

```
for file in $(find -name *.out); do grep -ol "No module" $file; done;
```

Which **should** just print the filenames of the failed runs. However, the scripts are python scripts which run with `python -u` (ensuring that content is flushed as it becomes available). Each script displays a `tqdm` progress bar, which effectively means these files are constantly updating. `grep` tends to hang on such files **sometimes**, and I'm not sure why, but it is often enough that it hangs after grepping just 8-10 files. I've tried

```
for file in $(find -name *.out); do tail -n 2 $file | grep  "No module" && echo $file ; done;
```

(which will need some adjustments to produce an identical output) but it suffers from the same problem. Even `tail -n 2` struggles when a file is currently being updated. Is there any way to have bash take a snapshot of the file and ignore incoming updates if they occur, as I just need to look at the second last line (which contains the error).

Comment: Make a copy of the file and grep that.

Comment: Note that `for file in $(anything)` is an antipattern; see [BashPitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) describing the bugs it causes (also relevant is [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)). For what to do instead, see [Using Find](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind).

Comment: `grep` and `tail` should not be hanging while files are being written. Which OS is this?

Comment: I could conceive of this happening if one of the files was _not_ a regular file but in fact something like a socket, but otherwise on a sane UNIXlike OS there should indeed be no hang. (Edit: John Kugelman's proposed explanation below makes a lot of sense; if that's the case, one can just turn off the progress bars, or tell the program to switch to a log format meant for programmatic consumption instead of human readers).

Comment: I suspect the progress bars are printed by writing lots of lines with `\r` carriage returns or ANSI escape codes to move the cursor but no `\n` newlines. That would make them appear as incredibly long lines to `grep` and `tail`, which could conceivably slow them down if the lines are long enough.

Comment: If that's what it is, the best answer is probably to redirect progress-bar output to stderr instead of stdout, which is where it properly belongs (or even better, direct to a TTY). Cursor control codes and the like shouldn't be going to log files in the first place.

Comment: @Kraigolas, that said, which operating system is this? Windows in particular doesn't reliably follow proper UNIX semantics (which require a file being written by one program to still be readable by others at the same time). (I say doesn't "reliably" because NTFS itself has the proper support, but not all the syscalls used to access it do; the situation as a whole is messy there).

Comment: @JohnKugelman That makes a lot of sense, because when I move the files from linux to windows they are all printed to new lines.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This is linux-gnu (from `echo $OSTYPE`). This isn't a log file, it actually just holds exactly what would have went to the terminal if the script was run normally (which would be both). However, to my understanding, tqdm goes to stderr anyway, and I am able to specify a separate file for this very easily. If you post your comment as an answer I will give it an upvote and when I test it, if it works, I'll mark it as best answer!

Comment: The insight as to the probable cause goes to John K. -- if the proposal works, he's the best person to get any reputation associated. (If neither of us does write up an answer, feel free to do so yourself, marking it "Community Wiki" if you prefer to disclaim ownership).

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `tqdm` if the output is not a **tty**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import os
from tqdm import tqdm

if not os.isatty(1):
    def tqdm(iterable):
        return iterable

# you script here ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your scripts are piping `stderr/fd(2)` (as well as `stdout/fd(1)`) to these log files, you could disable-tqdm-on-non-terminal (i.e. file) output:

```py
from sys import stderr
from tqdm import tqdm

for i in tqdm(..., disable=not isatty(2)):
    ...
```

Alternatively just ramp up the interval between progressive updates:

```py
from tqdm import tqdm

for i in tqdm(..., mininterval=1):
    ...
```

This would mean fewer lines for `grep` to parse.